# sql database connecting in visual studio web developer

Tags: asp.net, sql

There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store.

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:

> Unable to open the physical file "C:\Users\sooraj.r\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2010\WebSites\FormsDemo\App_Data". Operating system error 5:
>   "5(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15105)". Cannot
>   attach the file 'C:\Users\sooraj.r\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\WebSites\FormsDemo\App_Data' as database 'FormsDemo.mdf'.

Comment: you are using a external database .mdf may be sql server 2008 are try to add this database file in project without using server or any EMS.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You've posted an error message that is pretty much self-explanatory. Did you try anything that it suggests you to do??

Comment: im tryng to connect to database from visual studion developer but im getting this error... actually i need to create a login page and shuld giv an authorization and authentication for tht...